# Converter número em string para inteiro PHP

Tags: php, string, int, conversão

Estou convertendo uma string  para inteiro em PHP, porém no retorno do `settype($variavel, "integer")`, ou `(int)$variavel` me trazem um valor nulo ou igual a 1.

Tem outra forma de tentar a conversão?

O código que estou com problema é esse:

```
<script type="text/html" id="javo-map-tab-infobx-content">
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified pull-right">
                    <a id="botaoBrief" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="window.javo_map_tab_func.brief_run(this);" data-id="{post_id}">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php _e("Briefaaaa", "javo_fr"); ?>
                    </a>

<?php
$idPost = '{post_id}';

var_dump($idPost); // resultado->   string(9) "5266"

$idPost = intval($idPost); //resultado-> 0

echo gettype($idPost); //resultado-> integer
```

Comment: intval($idPost); Worked for me

Comment: Saudações, Welisson. Nós estamos no Stack Overflow em Português, então pode falar em português mesmo; além disso, a sua sugestão já foi dada nas outras respostas, então não ficou muito claro no que você quis agregar com a sua resposta. Se foi só um relato que funcionou, você pode simplesmente utilizar o sistema de votos do site. Saiba mais fazendo o [tour] e acessando a [help].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se está a retornar 1 através do `intval` poderá ser o facto da variável ser um array.
Atenção a isso. Tenha a certeza que a variável é uma string.

**Exemplo:**

```
$variavel = '200';
$variavel = intval($variavel);
```

Isto irá retornar: 200

**Se for:**

```
$variavel = array('foo'=>'200');

$variavel = intval($variavel);
```

Isto ira retornar: 1

**Se for possível poderia colocar o debug da variável aqui?**

**Faça debug assim:**

```
   if(is_array($idPost))
        echo 'Array';
    else
        echo 'Not Array';

die;
```

Answer (score 5):

`settype` retorna se o tipo da variável foi trocado com sucesso(true ou 1), null ou 0 para falha. Pode fazer um cast para int.

```
<?php
   $variavel = (int) '200';
   echo gettype($variavel)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a função `intval`.

```
intval("123"); // retorna 123
```

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Outras funções do mesmo tipo:

```
boolval($val);  // retorna o valor de $val convertido para um booleano
floatval($val); // retorna o valor de $val convertido para um float
strval($val);   // retorna o valor de $val convertido para um string
```

Comment: Utilizando intval o retorno que eu estou tendo é 1.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `$variavel`?

Comment: Eu estou recebendo um id de um post do wordpress.
Ele vem pra mim como string, exemplo $variavel = '5625''

Comment: Dê um `var_dump` nessa variável para saber o tipo e o conteúdo do que você está recebendo.

Comment: O valor recebido é uma String.
A resposta que eu tive foi: string(9) "5266"

Comment: A resposta do Rodrigo está correta. Se retorna 1 para você sendo que a variável contém "5266", então vc tem algum problema antes do intval().

Comment: Daniel o problema é que nao tem nenhum codigo entre essa variavel que recebo do wordpress e o momento onde eu faço a conversão.

Comment: @GiulioCosta poste o trecho do código na pergunta.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti postei o código e os retornos que estou tendo.

Comment: `boolval` só funciona para versões maiores que `5.5.0`

Comment: Verifique se as aspas não estão vindo junto do número como elemento da sua string e contabilizando no `var_dump()`.

Comment: intval() não deve ser usado em objetos, pois isso irá emitir um erro de nível E_NOTICE e retornar 1.