# Transformar string em inteiro no PHP

Tags: php, string

Tenho duas classes se comunicando. Uma delas retorna um getter com o mês digitado no formulário, e a outra classe recebe esse getter dentro da função cal_days_in_month(). O problema é que o campo mês desta função só aceita inteiro, e como a informação vem de um getter ele vem como string, alguém saberia de alguma solução?

Segue a classe que recebe os dados do formulário. Recebe.php:

```
<?php

class RecebeDados
{
    private $mes, $ano, $feriado, $beneficio, $date;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
    }

    public function recebeForm($dados)
    {
        $this->mes = $dados['mes'];
        $this->ano = $dados['ano'];
        $this->feriado = $dados['feriado'];
        $this->beneficio = $dados['beneficio'];
    }

    public function getMes()
    {   
        return $this->mes;
    }

    public function getAno()
    {
        return $this->ano;
    }

    public function getFeriado()
    {
        return $this->feriado;
    }

    public function getBeneficio()
    {
        return $this->beneficio;
    }
}

$recebe = new RecebeDados();
$recebe->recebeForm($_POST);

require_once 'CalculaBeneficio.php';

$calcBeneficio = new CalculaBeneficio();
$calcBeneficio->calcDias();
$calcBeneficio->calcBeneficio();
```

A classe que utiliza esses dados. Calcula.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'RecebeDados.php';

class CalculaBeneficio extends RecebeDados
{
    public $diasUteis, $totalDiasMes, $result, $recebeDados;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->recebeDados = new RecebeDados();
    }

    public function calcDias()
    {
        $this->diasUteis = 0;

            // Obtém o número de dias no mês 
        $this->totalDiasMes = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->recebeDados->getMes(), $this->recebeDados->getAno()); 

        for($dia = 1; $dia <= $this->totalDiasMes; $dia++) {

            // Verifica os dias úteis do mês (seg a sex)
        $timeStamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->recebeDados->getMes(), $this->recebeDados->getDia(), $this->recebeDados->getAno());
        $diaSemana = date("N", $timeStamp);

        if ($diaSemana < 6) $this->diasUteis++;

        }

        return $this->diasUteis;

        }

    public function calcBeneficio()
    {
            //  Faz calculo para retirar os feriados
        $this->result = $this->totalDiasMes - $this->recebeDados->getFeriado();

            //  Calcula o beneficio
        return $this->result *= $this->recebeDados->getBeneficio();

        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
}
```

O erro que apresenta quando preencho o formulário é:

```
Warning: cal_days_in_month(): invalid date.
```

Isso porque na documentação diz que os campos devem ser inteiros, e eles estão vindo como string dos getters.

Há outro tópico com relação a converter string em inteiro:
[Converter número em string para inteiro PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83569/converter-n%C3%BAmero-em-string-para-inteiro-php)

Mas as soluções neste tópico não resolveram o meu problema.

Grato!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Converter número em string para inteiro PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83569/converter-n%c3%bamero-em-string-para-inteiro-php)

Comment: Eu achei este tópico antes de publicar ele. E como comentei na sua resposta, a solução apresentada no link passado não resolveu

Comment: Então será bom você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o erro que está dando.

Comment: Mas o erro é exatamente esse. Mas a solução passada no link nao resolveu

Comment: @Gabriel isso não vai funcionar, pois os dados que você preenche no `RecebeDados` não faz nenhuma relação depois com o `CalculaBeneficio` (que na verdade cria uma nova instância no construtor).

Comment: De fato você está utilizando heranca e composicão entre duas classes no mínimo estranhas. Não vejo porque utilizar heranca neste caso e a composicão parece estar mal definida.

Comment: @Gabriel o certo seria você editar a pergunta pois o seu problema está relacionado com a herança entre as suas classes.

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer efetuando um *[`casting`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting)* utilizando os modificadores `int` ou `integer`:

```
$string = '100';
$int = (int) $string;
```

Ou utilizando a função [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php):

```
$string = '100';
$int = intval($string);
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelo retorno. Estas duas opções eu ja havia tentado realizar mas não deu certo, continuou apresentando o mesmo problema. Tinha colocado intval($this->recebeDados->getMes()) e (int)$this->recebeDados->getMes(). E nenhum dos dois resolveu o problema, então tentei converter direto na variavel antes de chamar os getters, assim (int)$this->recebeDados, ou assim intval($this->recebeDados). E também não resolveu   :/

Comment: Dá um `var_dump` nessas saídas aí, tem algo além da conversão nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar mudar o seu código um pouquinho:

Pra fazer funcionar use essas linhas:

```
require_once 'CalculaBeneficio.php';

$calcBeneficio = new CalculaBeneficio($_POST);
$calcBeneficio->calcDias();
$calcBeneficio->calcBeneficio();
```

No `construct` da classe `CalculaBeneficio`:

```
public function __construct($data)
{
    parent::__construct($data);
}
```

Na classe `CalculaBeneficio` onde tiver `$this->recebeDados` você apaga o recebeDados, exemplo:

```
$this->recebeDados->getMes(); // Antigo
$this->getMes(); // Novo
```

No construtor da classe `RecebeDados`:

```
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
    $this->mes = $data['mes'];
    $this->ano = $data['ano'];
    $this->feriado = $data['feriado'];
    $this->beneficio = $data['beneficio'];
}
```

Aqui você pode ler mais sobre [herança em PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

Comment: Tentei desta forma mas o erro continua aparecendo quando preencho o formulario. O erro que apresenta é:  Warning: cal_days_in_month(): invalid date.

Comment: @Gabriel Verifica os dados que estão vindo no `$this->getMes()` e no `$this->getAno()` compara com a sintaxe do [call_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

Comment: Esta retornando null

Comment: @Gabriel vê o que tá vindo dentro do $data no `__construct`

Comment: @Gabriel desculpe, tinha esquecido da classe RecebeDados, editei a resposta, você vai precisar mexer no `__construct` da classe `RecebeDados`.